# Types being coerced to "any" and "Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated" error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, joi

I have an NPM module that i've created, with some Typescript typings... and now I am trying to use this module in another application, and I am getting some issues! This could get confusing, so I will try to simplify the examples by omitting properties that aren't relevant to the question...

In the module I have the following in my index.d.ts file:

```
import * as Joi from 'joi';
import { RequestHandler } from 'express';

export interface ISteadyOptions {
  customTypes?: IParamType[],
  middleware?: (RequestHandler|ErrorRequestHandler)[],
}

export interface IParamType {
  name: string
  validator: (param: object) => Joi.ArraySchema
}
```

Meanwhile, in my application I have something like this:

```
const opts: ISteadyOptions = {
  middleware: [
    logger('dev'),
    express.static('images')
  ],
  customTypes: [
    {
      name: "point",
      validator: function(param) {
        return Joi.array().items(
          config.getAvailableGroups()
        )
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

The idea being that I can only add Express request handlers into the `middleware` array, and I can define a customType (e.g. `point`) with a Joi schema alongside it to be ran when required.

**Problem 1 - I can put anything inside `opts.middleware`**

For example, TypeScript says this is totally valid:

```
middleware: [
  logger('dev'),
  express.static('images'),
  "not a request handler"
]
```

If I add something else invalid elsewhere in the `opts` object, then when VSCode gives me the error, I can see that for some reason the type for `middleware` has been changed to `any[]`.

I can't figure out why this would have happened?

**Problem 2 - I can't get my `validator` function to work**

I get this error:

```
Types of property 'customTypes' are incompatible.
Type '({ name: string; description: string; validator: (param: object) => ArraySchema; example: string[...' is not assignable to type 'IParamType[]'.
Type '{ name: string; description: string; validator: (param: object) => ArraySchema; example: string[]...' is not assignable to type 'IParamType'.
Type '{ name: string; description: string; validator: (param: object) => ArraySchema; example: string[]...' is not assignable to type 'IParamType'.
Types of property 'validator' are incompatible.
Type '(param: object) => ArraySchema' is not assignable to type '(param: object) => ArraySchema'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Type 'ArraySchema' is not assignable to type 'ArraySchema'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Types of property 'validate' are incompatible.
Type '{ <T>(value: T): ValidationResult<T>; <T>(value: T, options: ValidationOptions): ValidationResult...' is not assignable to type '{ <T>(value: T): ValidationResult<T>; <T>(value: T, options: ValidationOptions): ValidationResult...'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Type 'ValidationResult<any>' is not assignable to type 'ValidationResult<any>'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Types of property 'error' are incompatible.
Type 'ValidationError' is not assignable to type 'ValidationError'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Types of property 'details' are incompatible.
Type 'ValidationErrorItem[]' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrorItem[]'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Type 'ValidationErrorItem' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrorItem'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Types of property 'path' are incompatible.
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type string.
```

I was able to replicate my use case (shown below), and it worked as expected... I'm obviously doing something wrong... but I have no idea what?!

```
import { RequestHandler, ErrorRequestHandler } from 'express';
import * as Joi from 'joi';

interface IValidator {
  validator: (data: string) => Joi.AnySchema
}

const thing: IValidator = {
  validator: data => {
    return Joi.string()
  }
}

// this works
console.log(
  thing.validator("javascript")
);

interface IMiddleware {
  middleware: (RequestHandler|ErrorRequestHandler)[]
}

const thing2: IMiddleware = {
  middleware: [
    (res, req, next) => {
      return next()
    },
    "foo" // this causes an error
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the first issue. But I would either use `RequestHandlerParams` or `Array<RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler>` as the type.

As for the second issue. You are using different types than what are defined. Not sure what type you are passing in to customTypes but `{ name: string; description: string; validator: (param: object) => ArraySchema; example: string[...` does not match the given declaration you have. So not sure how you typed the incoming data.

`(param: object) => ArraySchema' is not assignable to type '(param: object) => ArraySchema` is caused by two different types but they are named the same thing. So you are doing `import {ArraySchema} from 'joi';` in one place and `import {ArraySchema} from 'different-lib';` in another place. Causing the types to clash. This goes for several of the duplicated type errors you have.

Comment: Problem 2 was down to the fact that I had different versions of Joi installed on the different projects!